# What is the name of the song Guitar man plays on the stage in Dirtwater?

Tags: game-music-identification, west-of-loathing

I've been trying to get that damned song's name that has been haunting me and I find myself leaving my character for 10-15 minutes on the stage at Dirtwater just to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that must be either [*Sit fer a Spell*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8wUy_9iR00), [*Dirtwater Jam Band*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4U1ksQnhmg), or [*These Boots Were made for Moseyin'*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaksjPqmmdk).

These songs - like all others of the [soundtrack](https://ryanike.bandcamp.com/album/west-of-loathing-original-game-soundtrack) - were created by [Ryan Ike](https://www.ryanike.com/).

Comment: Bless thee, soul. I may die in peace in now.